# Mockito.doThrow with custom stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, mockito, stack-trace

I'm trying to unit test a specific scenario that requires me to throw an exception with a specific stack trace element.

Basically I do:

```
    final RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException();
    exception.setStackTrace(
        new StackTraceElement[] {
            new StackTraceElement(
                Claims.class.getCanonicalName(),
                "add",
                "Claims.java",
                123
            )
        }
    );
    Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(stk).process(project, claim);
```

But in the method under test the exception thrown doesn't contain this element, it contains a stack trace to the unit test class.

Is it possible for Mockito to throw the exception exactly as I want? Or will it always override the stack trace?

Comment: Why do you need a particular stack trace to be used in your test? Relying upon the exception message is brittle; relying upon the stack trace is even more so.

Comment: I have a handler that sends all exceptions into a queue. But if I have an exception in the queue mechanism it goes into a loop. I want to send exception into a queue only if the exception is NOT from the queuing method - So I want to check the StackTraceElements to see where the exception is coming from.

Comment: that sounds like you would do better by throwing exceptions of a particular type from the queuing method (say, `QueueingMethodException`), and then have your catch ignore those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of throwing an exception will rewrite its stacktrace, even if it's done by `doThrow`.
One way around this is not to use a real exception, but to mock it:

```
RuntimeException exception = mock(RuntimeException.class);
when(exception.getStackTrace()).thenReturn(
    new StackTraceElement[] {
        new StackTraceElement(
            Claims.class.getCanonicalName(),
            "add",
            "Claims.java",
            123
        )
    }
);
```

Comment: @Mureinki Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use `doAnswer` or `thenAnswer` to throw the exception instead:

```
Mockito.doAnswer((invocation) -> {
    throw exception;
}).when(stk).process(project, claim);
```

This will keep your original stack trace intact instead of having Mockito mangle it.